# Synaptics touchpad: Left button full width

Tags: touchpad, synaptics

Linux Mint 17.1 "Rebecca".
Asus ux32vd notebook.
Synaptics touchpad (clickpad). Using the GUI to configure.

The following works as intended:

- "Tap to click" is disabled (I only want real clicks to act as clicks)
- Two-finger scrolling.
- Two-finger click = right button.
- Three-finger click = middle button.

Only the one-finger click does not work as intended.
Currently the behavior is:

- One-finger click in left side of clickpad: Left click.
- One-finger click in right side of clickpad: Right click.

What I would like instead:

- One-finger click anywhere in the clickpad: Left click.
- Right and middle click are already covered by the multi-finger clicks.

Everything else can be configured with the GUI, but maybe this one can't?

### The question

- How can I configure the touchpad to behave like explained above?
  (If this involves a config file, please say which one)

### Bonus questions

(maybe these can be covered in the comments, we'll see)

- If this requires to change a config file somewhere, does it conflict with the GUI settings? Does it mean I need to do all with config file?
- Will the config file be loaded automatically on reboot, wake up, etc? (I had difficulties with this in a previous Mint version)
- Are the GUI settings saved in the same config file? (I think not)
- Where would I file this as a feature request?

Thanks!